# Remote binding for treeview in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I can get only the level 1 items and the items which have children show an arrow sign next to it, but on expanding them I get those top level items again. So, this is going on in a kind of loop. I am unble to show Level 2. This is my first time with the kendo treeview. My codes are as-

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
          .Name("treeview")
          .DataTextField("Name")
          .LoadOnDemand(true)
          .HighlightPath(true)
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read
                .Action("EntitiesForTreeView", "Home")

        ))
```

And controller code is-

```
 public JsonResult EntitiesForTreeView()
    {
        List<UserGuide> userGuideList = GetUserGuideInfo();

        var myEntity = from e in userGuideList
                       where (e.Level == "L1")
                       select new
                       {
                           id = e.ID,
                           Name = e.UserGuideDescription,
                           hasChildren = (from x in userGuideList
                                          where x.ScreenName == e.ScreenName &&
                                            x.Level == "L2"
                                          select x).Any()
                       };
        return Json(myEntity, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**userGuideList** has all the 6 rows, and **myEntity** has the 4 Level 1 items as per my DB.
My database structure is as follows(Id 5 and 6 should be under Id 1)

Id  **Type**    *Des*   **Level**

1   **Main**    *All*   **L1**
2   **Price**   *Future* **L1**
3   **notes**   *Create notes* **L1**
4   **Events**  *events affecting price* **L1**
5   **Main**    *Create index* **L2**
6   **Main**    *Filter items* **L2**

Comment: have you tried looking at this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/remote-data-binding you will notice that they are passing in the id of the element they have clicked on. If you want to load all the data straight away then look at this example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/local-data-binding

Comment: I want to load all the data straight away without passing any Id. I did check the first link demo but I dont see the reason to pass any Id because I want to load all the items in one go. The second link is for local data... not the remote one. I need to pick the data from my DB.

Comment: As the remote mode is meant to be lightweight and only bring back the desired `node` level you will need to bind the control to a collection when the page loads as per the local binding example. If you have a large collection then this may take a little bit longer than the remote version. Given you would have to make only minimal changes to your existing code to implement the remote loading I would suggest that be the route you go down. As for the local data link that is showing the data being loaded from a DB and inserted into the `viewbag` collection and then being mapped to the control.

Comment: Thank you David for your help and giving me help... I passed the Id and only bringing the desired node at a time.